# SQL DB connection issue with flyway using windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, flyway

I am trying to use flyway tool for database migration. I am able to run it when using sql authentication but I have to use active directory authentication. my connection string looks like this
flyway.url=jdbc:sqlserver://:;databaseName=;authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;ssl=true
and I have flyway user and password in the conf file.

I am getting below error:
SQL State  : 08S01
Error Code : 0
Message    : The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification
path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:991bff03-8d3e-4326-99c8-a182a11d3ac7
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". ClientConnectionId:
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I found one article on flyway site about ssl support and it requires sql server certificates to be copied for flyway to use. I am looking for another workaround for that. Any help is appreciated.
thanks

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem, five times, "unable to find valid certification path to requested target." Are you trusting the SQL Server's self-signed X.509 (SSL) certificate?

Comment: Can you share the solution for this?

Comment: Hi, I am having similar problem. The error message I get is: ERROR: Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:sqlserver://ServerName:1443;databaseName=DBName;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;) for user 'ProdAD\devops': Login failed for user ''. ClientConnectionId:c37ce653-533b-4871-86f2-fc50d61b4789.


Were you able to connect using AD user and password?